# Creating fancy script text without using a font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, logo

I am looking to create a site for a musician so some eye catching logo for their band is in order. I want to just do a script type, calligraphy type, if you will, version of the band name. I'm fairly good with Photoshop, but I haven't done anything like this and can't find any tutorials. I'm probably not wording the question correctly, so the picture below is an example of what i'm trying to achieve. It's not just a font, it's like calligraphy on a computer.

Any ideas on how to do something like this? Like I said, I may not be typing in the right search terms to find what I want so if this has been asked or a tutorial is out there, if you could kindly point me to that, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's simply Calligraphy.

Comment: Right, but how does one do calligraphy in Photoshop? I guess I should have specified, most of my work in PS involves pictures, not so much creating things like this.

Comment: The same way any custom artwork is done. . . It's either painted or hand-drawn then scanned. For type, you're better off with a vector application such as Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: I see, I see. I'll start looking into scanning things in then. Thanks for that. I'll also see about Illustrator, only dabbled in that.

Comment: You can also use a [Wacom tablet](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/creative/intuos-pro-m) or similar device to draw directly into Photoshop, but the scanning option is easier (and cheaper). Wacom tablets have pressure sensitivity which works well for calligraphy and varying width lines.

Comment: Wow, i'd love to get ahold of one of those. That looks awesome.

Comment: @zburns12 Wacom Tablets are good, the [Wacom Cintiq](http://www.wacom.com/en/us/creative/cintiq-13-hd) is awesome - you can draw directly on the screen with that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One good way to get this type of design, is to get your self a big sheet of paper (A1) and a big square nibbed marker (1cm width or more), then draw out the letters with your whole arm - not wrist. This enables you to be free and fluid with your letters.
Once you have a few variations, then take a piccy with your phone, then load into Illustrator and get inking with the pen tool (other tools are available).

Comment: I'll do this, i've been needing an excuse to use my new fountain pens and work on my handwriting anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using an existing script font, expand it in Illustrator, then play with the formations to make it your own.